Running excel macro incorrectly causes next column over to be deleted
Sub CopyTextMacro()
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Columns("J").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
        .Columns("J").TextToColumns Destination:=.Columns("J"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, DecimalSeparator:="."
    End With
    
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Columns("K").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
        .Columns("K").TextToColumns Destination:=.Columns("K"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, DecimalSeparator:="."
    End With
    
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Columns("L").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
        .Columns("L").TextToColumns Destination:=.Columns("L"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, DecimalSeparator:="."
    End With
    
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Columns("M").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
        .Columns("M").TextToColumns Destination:=.Columns("M"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, DecimalSeparator:="."
    End With
    
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Columns("N").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
        .Columns("N").TextToColumns Destination:=.Columns("N"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, DecimalSeparator:="."
    End With
    
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Columns("Q").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
        .Columns("Q").TextToColumns Destination:=.Columns("Q"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, DecimalSeparator:="."
    End With
    
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Columns("R").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
        .Columns("R").TextToColumns Destination:=.Columns("R"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, DecimalSeparator:="."
    End With
    
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Columns("S").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
        .Columns("S").TextToColumns Destination:=.Columns("S"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, DecimalSeparator:="."
    End With
    
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Columns("T").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
        .Columns("T").TextToColumns Destination:=.Columns("T"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, DecimalSeparator:="."
    End With
    
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Columns("U").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
        .Columns("U").TextToColumns Destination:=.Columns("U"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, DecimalSeparator:="."
    End With
    
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Columns("V").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
        .Columns("V").TextToColumns Destination:=.Columns("V"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, DecimalSeparator:="."
    End With
    
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Columns("O").NumberFormat = "0"
        .Columns("O").TextToColumns Destination:=.Columns("O"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, DecimalSeparator:="."
    End With
    
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Columns("P").NumberFormat = "0"
        .Columns("P").TextToColumns Destination:=.Columns("P"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, DecimalSeparator:="."
    End With
End Sub

Running this snippet on my excel document somehow erases the next column over in this case 'K' Not sure how to fix or why this is happening. It correctly formats the 'J' column to date but then I can't format the next column as it deletes column 'K' and then I get a parser error in Visual Basic. K used to have the header 'PullRequestDate' before running snippet.


It would be easier to figure out if we had the "before" screenshot, not just the "after" screenshot, but my guess is that TextToColumns is just overwriting column K with whitespace that was present in column J before it got split. It is generally a bad idea to user TextToColumns inside a table because it will overwrite data in other columns.

It works exactly how it has been programmed.  The macro is not at fault.  You might want to re-phrase the title

Instead of processing the whole column, why not restrict to rows 2 to the end of your data?

I solved by having the destination be a temporary column instead of copying to itself and other columns accidentally. Also, for others struggling with macros, the record feature is amazing. Translates whatever you do in excel to a macro.
Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("AE:AE"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 3), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        
    Range("AE2:AE" & Cells(Rows.Count, "AE").End(xlUp).Row).Copy Destination:=Range("J2")
    
    Range("AE:AE").Delete

